# Basic App Architecture - Basic Observer / Observable in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I have a web-service written in JAVA that retrieves information about the weather and sends objects with that information.

This information should be crunched using the Observer-Observable design pattern in JAVA.

Also, I do need to send that information to a JList in SWING for the Graphical User Interface.

The model, is implemented as the following :

```
public class Model implements Observer{
// all the code that receives, override the update method and so on
}
```

Then, I need to put that object in an array and send that information to the UI.

The model receives automatically every 15 minutes a new weather object.

I want to know which is the best architecture to implement this. Im not sure if I should receive the information in the model, process it, and update the UI manually using a button or something like that on the UI that triggers some method.

The best scenario is to automatically update the JList after I processed the information on the Model.
In that case, should I implement the observer in both the Model AND the UI ? Because the model receives from the web service and the model sends to the UI.

Is a really basic problem, but Im not sure which is the best option to implement it, so I want some help.

Im adding the picture to clarify the situation.

[BASIC ARCHITECTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egxf1.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "Model" and the "View" on your diagram? I mean UI (Swing) has its own views, controllers and models...

Comment: I have a class that receives information from the web service, process it, and should use that information to populate the JList on the UI.

Comment: MVC would be the best solution. The model would be responsible for managing the data (at least retrieving and processing it); it would then generate a event notification of the change which would then be propagated to interested parties. How/what you do this is up to you. Swing has a number of "listener" patterns you might be able to re-use, but there's nothing stopping you from making your own if the other's don't meet your needs

Comment: Yes, the main problem is that I don't know how to update automatically the JList widget afer the List is updated. Can you guide myself how/where to look for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, **Swing** has its own data models, that implements some of the "Observer pattern" by managing and firing `Listener`s.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating

You might want to create and update such a model, firing the necessary listener after the update.

Comment: So, to clarify: I should receive the information from the web-service ( required ) on the "model" class. Then, populate - just in case - a List here. After that, implement a JList on Swing based on that Model previously populated.

Comment: I think your "Model" class should be implementing **Swing**'s model, too...